# Binary branching process with exponential distribution

Tags: probability, proof-verification, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Consider a particle $X_t^1$ which moves in space and assume that we have a countable family of exponential times ($exp(\nu)$ distributed) $T_1,....,T_N$ $N \in \mathbb{N}$, where $T_1$ is the time when particle 1 dies and splits into two new particles which get numbers 2 and 3. Then at $T_2$ particle $2$ dies and splits into two new particles and so on. This obviously leads to a tree structure. I now want to know the expectation for the number of particles at a given time $ \tilde{t}$.

My idea is as follows: The exponential distribution is memoryless so the probability for particle 1 to proliferate 3 times ( just hypothetically) is the same as if three particles proliferate each once. So I define $ \mathfrak{N}_t $ as the random variable which gives the probability for particle $1$ to split n times. As the occurence of these events is exponetial distributed $ \mathfrak{N}_t $ is a poisson process. If finally $\mathfrak{A}_t$ denotes the number of particles at time $t$ we have obviously $ \mathfrak{A}_t = \mathfrak{N}_t +1 $ and so the expecation is:

$ \mathbb{E}(\mathfrak{A}_t) = \mathbb{E}(\mathfrak{N}_t) +1  
=  \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\nu t)^{i}}{i!}e^{- \nu t}i + 1 = \nu t +1  $

So after time $t$ one expects $ (\nu t +1)$ particles. Is this correct?

Comment: Your solution is correct. Side note: the time when particle $k$ dies should be $T_1+T_2+\dots+T_k$, no? You are saying the time is $T_k$.

Comment: Oh yes you are right, thanks. Do I understand it correctly: If we start at $t=0$ and assume that $T_1 = 1$ second and $T_2 = 2$ seconds. Then particle 2 dies after $ 1+2 = 3$ seconds, so $T_2$ is just the time how long the particle lives. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, $T_2$ is how long particle number 2 lives. But in general, $T_k$ is not how long particle number $k$ lives. For example, particle three is born at the same time $T_1$ as particle 2, but dies at time $T_1+T_2+T_3$.

Comment: Hmmh, ok, so there is no possibility of how to think of these times?